# Use multiple string catalogs for localization in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, localization, string-catalog

I'm developing a SwiftUI app and have plenty of strings to translate so I started with a single string catalog in which I have all my translations and it works great. However, there are too many strings already and the catalog is becoming a bit too large.

**Is there a way of having multiple string catalogs and only including certain strings of text in each of them** (i.e., one string catalog per view or something similar)?

I have tried creating another string catalog but have to add the strings manually to this one and the translations don't get picked up by the code when compiling.

Comment: "and it's now difficult to find text in the strings" How? Xcode has a filter box that you can type in when you open up an xcstrings file.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I edited the question to better explain myself: the idea is that it would be more organised if I were able to put all the strings that appear under (e.g.,) the Profile View and all its subviews in one specific catalog so that I know where to look for the translations.

Comment: String Catalogs actually move away from the approach you are attempting. That is how it worked in previous versions, you could localize each View/Storyboard but it just adds to the work that needs to be accomplished.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. Thanks, @loremipsum. I'll just stick to a single localisation file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried creating another string catalog but have to add the strings manually to this one and the translations don't get picked up by the code when compiling.

It’s possible to have Xcode extract localisations for different strings tables (I.e a Strings Catalog), but you have to explicitly specify the “table name” in your Swift code.

For example:

```swift
Text("foo", tableName: "Settings")
```

This would then extract a string called `foo` into Settings.xcstrings.

While this is great, and [it’s encouraged by Apple in the WWDC 2023 session video on Strings Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10155/?time=379), having to specify the `tableName` every time is inconvenient and clutters your SwiftUI code somewhat which is why it’s not a common pattern we see being adopted.

You could work around this by extracting your string usage into some constants that you define with the help of `LocalizedStringResource` and if you want to go one step further, [there are even tools that will generate this code for you](https://github.com/liamnichols/xcstrings-tool)<sup>[1]</sup>. Using such tools though requires a bit of a shift in your way of thinking about the source of truth for localised content, something that [I wrote about in a blog post](https://liamnichols.eu/2023/10/02/taking-your-strings-catalogs-to-the-next-level.html).

---

<sup>1</sup>I am the author of the linked tool.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great answer. I can't upvote it as I don't have enough reputation yet... sorry :) I will take a look to the tool you provided, it looks very useful!